# Как обновить определенные ячейки в mysql?

Tags: mysql, python, python-3.x

Есть таблица в `mysql`, в ней первая колонка 'auto-increment'. Следующая - ссылка на `youtube` канал. Последующие - информация по `youtube` каналу.
Необходимо, чтоб код дописывал значения переменных из `python` в `mysql` в ту же строку, а не создавал каждый раз новую. Вот пример моего кода:

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(user=settings.db_login, password=settings.db_password,
                                               host=settings.dp_ip, database=settings.db_name, use_unicode=True,
                                               charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci')
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO youtube_videos (channel_ID, channel_name, channel_description, channel_startDate,
               channel_daysFromFoundation, channel_avatarImg, channel_region, channel_viewCount,
               channel_subscribersCount, channel_videoCount) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
               (channel_id, channel_title, channel_description, channel_startDate, channel_daysFromFoundation, channel_avatarImg,
                channel_region, channel_viewCount, channel_subscribersCount, channel_videoCount))
```

Нужно, что код не создавал каждый раз новую строку, а изменял значения в столбцах текущей

Код при замене `INSERT INTO` на `UPDATE`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/perforce/Social/test.py", line 87, in <module>
    channel_region, channel_viewCount, channel_subscribersCount, channel_videoCount))
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 515, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 488, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "D:\Minicanoda3\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(channel_ID, channel_name, channel_description, channel_startDate,
             ' at line 1
```

Добавил `WHERE`, но похоже, ошибка в синтаксисе

```
database = mysql.connector.connect(user=settings.db_login, password=settings.db_password,
                                               host=settings.dp_ip, database=settings.db_name, use_unicode=True,
                                               charset='utf8', collation='utf8_general_ci')
cursor = database.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID, channel_link FROM youtube_videos""")
ID = cursor.fetchall()[0]
cursor.execute("""UPDATE youtube_videos SET channel_ID = 'channel_id' WHERE ID FROM youtube_videos = %s""", ID)
```

Что-то опять не так исправил:

```
channel_id = 'UCVmcXaPBCHjVZWb82UK7AHw'
cursor.execute("""SELECT ID FROM youtube_videos WHERE channel_id is NULL""")
ID = cursor.fetchall()
ID = ID[0][0]
cursor.execute('UPDATE youtube_videos SET channel_ID = %s WHERE ID = %s ' % (channel_id,  ID))
```

Вот TraceBack:

```html
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'UCVmcXaPBCHjVZWb82UK7AHw' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Использовать `UPDATE` вместо `INSERT`

Comment: Тогда появляется ошибка, я добавил трейсбек выше

Comment: Ну так у `UPDATE` немного другой синтаксис нежели, чем у `SELECT`. Надо соответственно изменить запрос.

Comment: Так? cursor.execute("""UPDATE youtube_videos SET channel_ID = 'channel_id'"""). Насколько я понимаю, в этом случаю заменится вся колонка, а не нужно обновить только одну ячейку

Comment: Добавьте ещё `WHERE <тут условие, определяющее нужную строку>`

Comment: Я добавил, код с WHERE выше в самом вопросе, но, что-то не так

Comment: Не надо придумывать свой синтаксис SQL, надо пользоваться существующим. :) `WHERE ID = <нужный id>`

Comment: Я не придумывал, я старался :(  Я всё равно не понимаю, как дописать ;(

Comment: MYSQL ругается: "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"

Comment: Я несколько поверхностно понимаю, что происходит в запросе :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас проблема в том что вы хотите вставить несколько аргументов в обновление потому что когда вы вызываете (из вашего кода)

```
d = cursor.execute("""SELECT ID, channel_link FROM youtube_videos""")
```

Вы присваиваете 2 переменный которые хранятся в ячейках `ID` и `channel_link`( т.е. если вы выведите `d` то скорее всего у вас будет что то вроде
"Пример":`(2, то что храниться в ячейке channel_link)`)

Как пример обновление (мой пример) можете использовать примерно такую конструкцию. Тут вы вводите тот `ID` на который хотите поменять и меняете его на тот который был раньше

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(
                host=host,
                port=3306,
                user=user,
                password=password,
                db="test_create",
                charset='utf8',
                autocommit=True)
cur = conn.cursor()

number = input('Введите на какой заменить ID\n')
cur.execute("SELECT ID, real_name_test FROM Twiss")
c = cur.fetchall()[0]
print('Было {}'.format(c))
cur.execute("UPDATE Twiss SET ID = %s WHERE ID = %s ", (number,  c[0])) 
cur.execute("SELECT ID, real_name_test FROM Twiss")
print('Стало {}'.format(cur.fetchall()[0]))
```

Вывод:

```
> Введите на какой заменить ID
> 6
Было (12, '5')
Стало (6, '5')
```

Comment: Что-то опять идет не так, хотя. вроде, все переписал верно

Comment: @ЕвгенийАлександрович напишите что выводит `print(ID)` после последнего присваивания

Comment: После последнего присваивания print(ID) выводит 1. Тип {int}

Comment: так? cursor.execute('UPDATE youtube_videos SET channel_ID = '%s' WHERE ID = '%s' ' % (channel_id,  ID)). Просто опять ошибка invalid syntax

Comment: Ошибки нету, но и БД не обновилось

Comment: Попробовал вот так: cursor.execute("""UPDATE youtube_videos SET channel_ID = '%s' """ % (channel_id)). Без ID совсем, результат тот же