# mysql python создание запроса в бд

Tags: mysql, python

Использую такую функцию для записи данных в бд и постоянно ловлю ошибку.  В данной функции использую небольшое преобразование числа `m` в название столбца таблицы куда хочу положить данные.

```
def mmodule(self, m, val):
    mmod = {1:'user', 2:'config_user', 3:'data_user', 4:'static_user'}
    exec_DB('UPDATE `Main` SET %s=%s', (str(mmod[int(m)]), int(val)))
```

Получаю ошибку

```
ERROR exec_DB:  (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''config_user'=1' at line 1")
```

Подскажите как избавится от ковычек название таблицы 'config_user', т.к. из словаря вытаскивается название таблицы вида 'config_user' и происходит кривая подстановка в запрос

Comment: не помогает, таже самая ошибка

Comment: связанный вопрос : [Как обновить определенные ячейки в mysql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803127/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-mysql/803178#803178)

Comment: все получилось спасибо)!!!! первый вариант тоже рабочий забыл поставить %

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
exec_DB("UPDATE 'Main' SET '%s' = '%s'" % (mmod[m], val))
```

или вот так

```
exec_DB("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s" % (mmod[m], val))
```

Comment: Ребят вопрос в чем отличае между 
exec_DB("UPDATE 'Main' SET %s = %s" % (mmod[m], val))
и 
exec_DB('UPDATE `Main` SET %s=%s', (mmod[int(m)], int(val))
это из-за repr ? его надо переопределять в питоне? можете обьяснить в двух словах, пока точное определения на гуглить не могу

Comment: [Первый вариант открыт для `SQL Injection`, второй, скорее всего вывалится с ошибкой...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/804422/211923) ;-)