# Необходимо исправить запрос из питона в БД mysql

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Есть код для добавления в `mysql`:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM keywords WHERE name = '%s', " % (channel_name))
```

При добавлении значения в таблицу в поле `name`, поле `id` автоматически заполняется. Необходимо получить `id`, которому которому соответствует добавленная переменная `channel_name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html) вы ищете в поле(в моем случае это поле `real_name_test`) значения которое вы вводили в `name`

```
import pymysql
name = input('Введите что то:\n')
with pymysql.connect(
        host=host,
        port=3306,
        user=user,
        password=password,
        db="base",
        charset='utf8',
        autocommit=True) as cur:
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Twiss (real_name_test) VALUES (%s)", (name,))
    cur.execute("SELECT ID FROM Twiss WHERE real_name_test LIKE %s", (name,))
    row = cur.fetchall()
    print('ID которое заполнилось = {}'.format(row[0][0]))
```

---

Вывод

```
Введите что то:
Данный для заполнения SQL
ID которое заполнилось = 65
```

Comment: не используйте форматирование строк для обращения к БД. Используйте параметризированные запросы вместо этого.

Comment: @jfs  не совсем понял что вы имеете введу

Comment: вам [MaxU дал ссылку вчера на тему SQL injection](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804331/mysql-python-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b4/804352#comment1272042_804352)

Comment: параметризированный запрос: [``cursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s", ('webmaster@python.org',))``](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) -- обратите внимание форматирование строк (%) не используется

Comment: @jfs осознал косяк

Comment: чтобы картинку для памяти иметь, можно [на xkcd иллюстрацию на эту тему посмотреть](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @jfs очень сильно)