# Синтаксис python и psql

Tags: python, postgresql

Помогите с синтаксисом, нужно влить 3 переменные в базу, как правильно их перечислять? Данный код не работает.

```
insert23 = ("""INSERT INTO app (userid, req1, type) values (%s, %s, %s)""" % id % req1 % type)
cur.execute(insert23)

conn.commit()
```

Comment: `insert23 = "INSERT INTO app (userid, req1, type) values (%s, %s, %s)" % (id, req1, type)`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так же можете попробовать, ["*не используйте форматирование строк для обращения к БД. Используйте параметризированные запросы вместо этого.*"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805025/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%91%D0%94-mysql/805032#comment1273897_805032)

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO app (userid, req1, type) values (%s, %s, %s)", (id, req1, type))
```

или

```
insert23 = ("""INSERT INTO app (userid, req1, type) values (%s, %s, %s)""")
cur.execute(insert23, (id, req1, type))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert23 = "INSERT INTO app (userid, req1, type) values (%s, %s, %s)" % (id, req1, type)
```

[Pavel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/813280/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81-python-%D0%B8-psql#comment1290533_813280) помог, решено, спасибо