# Не сохраняется запись в БД

Tags: mysql, python, база-данных

Здравствуйте, возникла проблемка при записи данных в БД. Не могу понять, где проблема, в записи или в сохранении. Спасибо.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests
import time
from subprocess import call, PIPE
import MySQLdb

Routers = []
Hosts = []


db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                     user="root",
                     passwd="1234",
                     db="sqlrst",
                     charset='utf8')

db.autocommit = True
cursor = db.cursor()


def HttpRequest():
    cursor.execute("SELECT Host FROM Hosts")
    Hosts = cursor.fetchall()
    for x in Hosts:
        for z in x:
            try:
                request = requests.get(z)
                request.raise_for_status()
                r = 1
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException:
                r = 0
            cursor.execute(" UPDATE Routers SET Response = %s WHERE Router = %s ", (r, z))


def Pinger():

    cursor.execute("SELECT Router FROM Routers")
    Routers = cursor.fetchall()

    for x in Routers:
        for z in x:
            g = "ping -n 1 %s" % z
            p = call(g,
                     shell=True,
                     stdout=PIPE,
                     stderr=PIPE)
            if p != 0:
                r = 0
            else:
                r = 1
            cursor.execute(" UPDATE Hosts SET Response = %s WHERE Host = %s ", (r, z))


while True:
    HttpRequest()
    Pinger()
    db.commit()
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: ошибку какую либо выдает?

Comment: Нет, просто не обновляются данные в БД.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Как обновить определенные ячейки в mysql?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803127/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-mysql/803178#803178)

Comment: Несвязанный ответ

Comment: у Вас, как минимум, перепутаны местами запросы для апдейта. В `HttpRequest()` Вы делаете селект из `Hosts`, а обновлять пытаетесь `Routers`. В `Pinger()` - наоборот.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы спасли мне жизнь и нервы <3